# How to replace the Content of the OpenOffice Document Window/Win32 The documented solution not working?

Tags: vba, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer

I am using OO 3.0 and according to the official openoffice documentation (http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/StarDesktop) in order to replace the document this is the code required:

```
Dim Doc As Object
Dim Dummy() 
Dim Url As String
Dim SearchFlags As Long

SearchFlags = com.sun.star.frame.FrameSearchFlag.CREATE + _
              com.sun.star.frame.FrameSearchFlag.ALL
Url = "file:///C:/test.odt"
Doc = StarDesktop.loadComponentFromURL(Url, "MyFrame", SearchFlags, Dummy)
MsgBox "Press OK to display the second document."

Url = "file:///C:/test2.odt"
Doc = StarDesktop.loadComponentFromURL(Url, "MyFrame", SearchFlags, Dummy)
```

I tried it and it is not working, tried both from VB and OO Basic
what am I missing ? 
(I used all flags 23+8 and even 55 as the search flags mask)

Answer (score 0):

After reading more example scripts I tried setting the fame name manually:

```
vFrame = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame 
REM Here we set the frame name manually 
vFrame.setName("MyFrame")
```

While using loadComponentFromURL seems not to change the frame name, using the setName does change the frame name so after the first call to loadComponentFromURL I changed the frame using setName, and from now on it si working as expected